# Flutter Text("${sqlite_tbl[0]['body']") throwing NoSuchMethodError

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter

In this Flutter project, I am displaying information from a local sqlite database onto a page. There are many examples on the internet using the ListView.builder and ListTile to display. However, I am not in this case and I want to be able to access and display a specific column from a table.

First I create an instance of List then make that instance be a rawQuery like so.

```
List<Map> sqlite_tbl = db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM sample_table');
```

Then, in the build method for the page, I place some text in the appBar and in a SingleChildScrollView which is text I retrieve from the database like so..

```
child: new Text("${sqlite_tbl[0]['title']}",

child: new Text("${sqlite_tbl[0]['body']}",
```

When I access this page from the previous page, I get the red flash with NoSuchMethodError for a second or two, then the page will display with no errors. In my Run log, it will say The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: . So I assume it is the [0] where I retrieve the text, however once I remove that it will say that type argument type 'String' cannot be assigned to parameter type 'int'.

Does anybody know the correct way to retrieve this data or how to fix this issue? Please let me know if you need to see more of my code.

Answer (score 0):

The method `db.rawQuery` will return the type `Future<List<Map>>`. You should change your instantiation of the list to be:

```
List<Map> sqlite_tbl = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM sample_table');
```

You would then have to call `setState`.

**A better way for you to do this is something like:**

```
List<Map> sqlite_tbl;
bool initialized;

initState() {
  super.initState();
  initialized = false;
  _getData();
}

_getData() {
  db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM sample_table').then((results) {
    setState(() {
      sqlite_tbl = results;
      initialized = true;
    });
  }).catchError((e) { // do something });
}
```

And then you would build your UI depending on the value of `initialized`.

Comment: Then how do you format the query results into a new Text? and only retrieve a column of the table to output?

Comment: You have a list of maps where the keys are the column names. I recommend you create a data model and map the List<Map> results to your data model. Your data model should have a named constructor `fromMap` in which it constructs a model from the provided `Map`.

Comment: Would there by anyway around using a data model? I can change it but i'm under a time crunch, Is there anyway to get that error not to flash without it? maybe by just editing this line child: new Text("${sqlite_tbl[0]['title']}",?

Comment: I explained how to not get the error to flash in my answer. You should build the UI based upon the value of `initialized`. If `initialized` is false, then you should display something like a circular loading indicator because the data has not been retrieved and you will get an error for trying to access a list which has not been instantiated. You should only call `new Text(....)` once `initialized` is true because this indicates your data has been loaded.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, could you please upvote and mark it as answered?